# Cancel Button handle previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a save button that saves the checkbox and the number field, then makes a call to update those numbers.  I am adding a 'Cancel' button that I want to be able to use to revert the status to the previous state (prior to saving).  what is the best way to do this in React?
This is my code

```
class Alerts extends Component {
  state = {
    prevId: null,
    checked:  this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled,
    days:     this.props.preferences.last_order_alert
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Store prevId in state so we can compare when props change.
    // Clear out previously-loaded data (so we don't render stale stuff).
    if (props.dealerID !== state.prevId) {
      //update action goes here...
      //props.actions.getUsers(props.dealerID);
      return {
        prevId: props.dealerID
      };
    }

    // No state update necessary
    return null;
  }

componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('mountDays',this.props.preferences.last_order_alert);
  console.log('mountCheck',this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled);
  this.setState({ days: this.props.preferences.last_order_alert });
  this.setState( {checked: this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled})
};

  toggleAlerts = e => {
    console.log('lastOrderEnable', this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled);
    console.log('lastOrderDaysAlert', this.props.preferences.last_order_alert);
    this.props.actions.updateLastOrderAlert(
      this.props.preferences.id,
      this.props.dealerID,
      this.props.isGroup,
      this.props.preferences.last_order_alert = this.state.checked,
      this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled = this.state.days
    );
  };

  handleCheck = event => {
    console.log('called', {checked: Number(event.target.checked)  });
    this.setState({checked: Number(event.target.checked)  })
  };
handleChange = e => {
  console.log('days', {days: e.target.value});
  this.setState({days: e.target.value})
};

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className="preferenceContainer">
        <div className="preferenceRow lg">
          <div className="preferenceLabelWrapper">
            <div className="preferenceLabel">Enable Alert</div>
            <div className="preferenceSubLabel">
              Toggles the Last Order Alert Email
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="preferenceInput">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="preferenceRow">
          <div className="preferenceLabelWrapper">
            <div className="preferenceLabel">Days Since Last Order</div>
          </div>
          <div className="preferenceInput">
            <input
              type="number"
              value={this.state.days}
              // onBlur={this.handleAlertDays}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              style={{ width: "50px" }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
          <div className="preferenceRow" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <button
                className={'btn btn-default'}
                type="submit"
                onClick={this.componentDidMount}
            >Cancel
            </button>

            <button
                style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
                className={'btn btn-primary'}
                type="submit"
                onClick={this.toggleAlerts}
            >Save
            </button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Right now is currently saving the changes and rendering them back when I hit the cancel button(prior to hitting save). However, after hitting save and going to another page and then coming back, it does not render with the initial state in componentDidMount.

Comment: Dont user the componentDidMount onClick. Create a new function, and use that function in componentDidMount and also onClick.

Comment: @Peter could you expand on that please?

Comment: Regarding to Your question: setup some initialState, for what you can revert the current state. It can be stored in state, or in simple constant

Comment: componentDidMount is a Component lifecycle event. It is not a best practice to use it on other events.
Try to create some function like
initFunction = ()=> {
    console.log('mountDays',this.props.preferences.last_order_alert);
  console.log('mountCheck',this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled);
  this.setState({ days: this.props.preferences.last_order_alert });
  this.setState( {checked: this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled})
}
And dispatch that function at componentDidMount,like: 
componentDidMount(){this.initFunction()}
And also onClick={this.initFunction}

Comment: @Peter oh i see.  What would be the best practice to load the save state upon refreshing?  Looks like right now it does console log the correct 'componentDidMount' cycle but the checkMark or number is not set properly.

Comment: setup something like this:
componentDidMount(){ initFunction(); this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, initialState: { days: this.props.preferences.last_order_alert , checked: this.props.preferences.last_order_alert_enabled } })) }

and when you want to revert it, use that initialState: revert ()=> { this.setState(prev => { ...prev, days: prev.initialState.days, checked: days: prev.initialState.days }) }

Comment: @Peter set this up in the componentDidMount right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use lifecycle methods in onClick
2. If I understood correctly, you should use componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) lifecycle method to get previous props and previous state after change them. Every time after redrawing react will give you previous props and previous state in that method.

Sorry, if this is not what you need